# Creating Venn diagram with Venneuler

Tags: r, plot, venn-diagram

I used to create Venn diagram using "limma" but on one of the Shiny servers I need to use R version 3.3.0 and limma is not compatible with it. So I am trying **venneuler** and I am not able to create the plot. Can some one please share how to create the right plot if I want to make two/three/four way Venn diagram from a file containing  multiple columns -

Previous code used for **limma** -

```
count=read.table(file="htseq.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE,row.names=1)
a <- vennCounts(count[,1:4])
vennDiagram(a)
```

The input looks like this -

```
id  R148L_HAC   R148L_HANEB R148L_HANu
ENSMUSG00000000001  3   993 573
ENSMUSG00000000003  0   0   0
ENSMUSG00000000028  2   0   10
ENSMUSG00000000031  1   843 149
ENSMUSG00000000037  0   0   0
ENSMUSG00000000049  99  12362   1228
```

The code with Venneuler -

```
 count=read.table(file="htseq.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE,row.names=1)
a1 <- cbind(count$R148L_HAC, count$R148L_HANEB, count$R148L_HANu)
v <- venneuler(a1)
plot(v)
```

This creates following plot -

[image]

Comment: For the matrix input `venneuler` (and `limma::venn` too) expects a matrix of binaries or logicals, not a matrix of counts. I am surprised it did not throw you an error. You need to find a way to either provide a matrix of logicals or a string with the set relationships.